# Git Ignore not working for folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have files in folder structure like this : `freelancer\Presentation\ABC.Web\Plugins\Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.dll` , there are other files

I want to ignore the whole Plugins folder

I tried to put each of the following in the `.gitignore` file, but none of them work.

```
1. Presentation/ABC.Web/Plugins
2. Presentation/ABC.Web/Plugins/*   
3. */Presentation/ABC.Web/Plugins/* 
4. Presentation//ABC.Web//Plugins 
5. "Presentation//ABC.Web//Plugins" 
6. Presentation\\ABC.Web\\Plugins   
7. "Presentation\\ABC.Web\\Plugins"
```

I even tried clearing the cache and restarting git but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "restarting git"? Show your output for the following command: `git status`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git requires two `*`'s if you want to (recursively) ignore a whole folder and its contents, to an infinite depth.

From the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A trailing "`/**`" matches everything inside. For example, "`abc/**`" matches all files inside directory "`abc`", relative to the location of the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.

That means the following should work:

```
Presentation/ABC.Web/Plugins/**
```

Please note that all of the files you want to ignore have to be untracked (i.e., never committed in the past). If you want to ignore already commited files, [this](http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/) may help you.